# angular 4 access template context variable from a funcion on template

Tags: typescript, angularjs-directive, angular-cli

My code is (I am not writing code that is not useful for my question):

myComponent.component.ts

```
/* some imports */  

@Component({
  /* some code */
})

export class GenericListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    sliceFrom: number; // I want to use this variable on a function on my template

    constructor(/* some stuff */) { }

    myFunction(stuff: number) {
        this.sliceFrom = 15*stuff
    }

}
```

as you see I can access to the value of sliceFrom in the component template, but not inside a function:

myComponent.component.html

```
<!-- here it works fine  -->
<p>The value of my variable is: {{ sliceFrom }}</p>

<!-- here it is not working  -->
<tr *ngFor='let item of elements.slice({{ sliceFrom }}, {{ sliceFrom + 14 }})'>
```

I need to pass the value of sliceFrom to typescript's slice() method in order to paginate the array of my list. But it is not working.. I also tried using quotes like this:

```
<tr *ngFor='let item of elements.slice('{{ sliceFrom }}', '{{ sliceFrom + 14 }}')'>
```

but it is not working.
So my question is: How can i pass a variable to a **function** on my component template??

thanks to all of you that will try to help me :)

Comment: Remove the `{{` and the `}}` in `*ngFor`, that is the syntax for template binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clarification for my comment:

Change this:

```
<tr *ngFor='let item of elements.slice({{ sliceFrom }}, {{ sliceFrom + 14 }})'>
```

To this:

```
<tr *ngFor='let item of elements.slice(sliceFrom, sliceFrom + 14)'>
```

And it should work.

You don't do `{{ elements }}` in `*ngFor` and it's just the same with `sliceFrom`.